# What can I use for an antenna?

Tags: arduino, rf, wireless

I'm building a wireless project using a [RFM12B](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9582) RF transceiver. As I understand it I have to make an antenna myself, and its length has to match the frequency (in this case 165mm).

BUT, can I use anything as an antenna? I have this [hook-up wire](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8023), can I use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solid core wire of the correct length will work fine for your antenna.  The hook-up wire from Sparkfun looks OK.

I have done exactly the same with an RFM12 before - I assume you are using the version with pins which has a hole on the PCB for the antenna wire. Here's a picture of my setup, on the left a PCB with rubberised antenna and on the right a breadboard with a small wire whip:

[image: RFM12 setup]

Comment: Here's a picture of my setup, on the left a PCB with rubberised antenna and on the right a breadboard with a small wire whip: [picture of breadboard and PCB RFM12](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/1681/rcx6.jpg)

Comment: Do you want me to edit that image into your answer? It looks like a useful addition.

Comment: Please - I am struggling to understand mini-Markdown it seems!

Comment: Have done. Unless it's changed I think you need a reputation of 15 to post images, it's just to stop new users posting spam / junk.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much anything conductive can be used as an antenna, so I don't see a problem using that hook-up wire. But from a practical point of view especially if your device is moving around the geometry of the antenna will change as the wire flops around.

If that's likely to be a problem you might want to consider something a bit more rigid like say coat hanger wire or a thicker piece of copper wire. Some of the larger sizes of mains flex have a solid core that can be used effectively to make antennas and it's also nice and easy to solder.